# Problem with success

Tags: jquery, ajax

Maybe i get minuses for this question, but i have problems with `success` and i really don't see differences between example of using `success` from jQuery documentation:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

and my code:

```
$('#my_form').live('submit', function(){
    var data = $("#form_for_item").serialize();
    var url = '/something/add_something/' + $('#form_for_item').attr('name') + '/';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            alert('problem!')
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    return false;
});
```

For more i can say that data is sent via post and save in my database, and for more than more i can say that when i have `success: alert('problem!')` there is no problem.
What is wrong with my `success`?

Comment: missing argument in callback function,I think.
Try: success: function(response)

Comment: Your `success` handler isn't getting called? Great question title BTW.

Comment: Not being able to deal with success and having no problem when there's a `'problem!'`... you're a difficult person. ;-P

Comment: @ mu is too short it seems that my `success` handler isn't called.

Comment: Try adding an `error` callback, if that gets called then your server isn't responding with the right HTTP status code. And try dropping the `dataType: 'json'`, the server might not be sending back JSON and that could cause trouble.

Comment: @deceze I don't know myself enought good to know that what You say :)

Comment: @mu is too short BINGO withdropping the `dataType: 'json'`. My server not sending JSON and i don't know that it is important when have `dataType: 'json'`, and even if i will know, maybe i will missed that. Thank You. I hope You can understand my englishlike words.

Comment: Cool, I put that down as an answer if you want something to accept and so future searchers might find an answer to similar problems. Your English is good enough to understand, "problem with success" has a funny meaning in English.

Comment: So i learned something new about english too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your server isn't returning JSON data. Usually you can leave it up to `$.ajax` to figure out what sort of data the server is responding with by checking the Content-Type header and possibly other means. Try dropping the `dataType`.

Also, using:

```
success: alert('problem!')
```

Gets you your `alert` because that will be executed while the `$.ajax` call's options object is being built and there won't be a success callback at all.

Answer (score 2):

You're overlooking the most important aspect in the documented code:

```
context: document.body,
```

`context` as it suggests, specifies the context of the callbacks - `success`, `error`, `complete`.

So in the documented code's success block, `$(this)` means `$(document.body)`.

By default, the context is `$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `.ajax()` and not a DOM object.

Another **issue** I see with your code is this:

```
var url = '/something/add_something/' + $('#form_for_item').attr('name') + '/';
```

You're using an absolute url (which doesn't resolve as it lacks FQDN) which is resulting in an error, hence your success never executes.
To verify, add an error handler and see.

Your url ideally should be somthing like:

```
// relative path
var url = 'something/add_something/' + $('#form_for_item').attr('name') + '/';
```

or

```
// complete path
var url = 'http://domain.com/something/add_something/' + $('#form_for_item').attr('name') + '/';
```

Comment: This helps me with my jquery knowledge in general. Thank You for that. My problem maker was `dataType: 'json'`because my server didn't recived data in this format.

Comment: I know that i should do experiments even if i have good answer but my time is running out ;/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this` in your AJAX callback is something entirely else than `this` in your `.live` callback, since `this` changes dynamically with context. To get the right object, you need to save a reference to it:

```
.live('submit', function () {
    var that = this;

    ...

        success : function () {
            $(that).addClass("done");
        }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Maybe i still don't see something and maybe it is because my question is not enought explicity, but i still don't know how to call alert. Does `alert` need specified `this` somewhere?
BTW that what You said have value for me because i didn't know that before.

Comment: @Cris As far as I understood, when you `alert` in your `success` callback you *are* seeing the alert? Just the class is not getting set?

Comment: @Cris OK, then you should probably write this better in your question and this answer is not the complete answer. Try a callback on `complete` and debug all the parameters that are passed to it.

Comment: I will try with `complete`. Sorry if i was not enought explicity in my question.